# Install App By USB [Install canceled by user]

Tags: android, adb

I'm able to install application by USB to my Android Device.

But, mistakenly when Allow/Deny installation popup shown on Android .. I clicked Deny and also checked Remember my Choice.

Now, Every Attempt to install app via usb (ADB) failed with error `com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED                                                                                                                _USER_RESTRICTED: Install canceled by user`

[image]

I clicked Deny with Remember choice checked. Now all installations are failing.

I restarted my device, Enabled Disabled Developer Options But, didn't worked :(

How to reset my choice ?

Comment: uninstall your application and try installing it back.

Comment: Tried but, all further installations are getting failed.. with same error.. Install canceled by user.

Comment: are you on miui?

Comment: try user apelsinex's solution from http://en.miui.com/thread-544718-1-1.html. It happened to me yesterday, and that solution worked.

Answer (score 18):

I made same thing as you.

TDLR: Apps -> Permissions -> Install via USB -> Uncheck App

- [You need to find App via search in configuration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o1Y8.jpg)
- [Go to the permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcvVT.jpg)
- [Into Install via USB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NfKL.jpg)
- uncheck app, you've blocked.

Answer (score 2):

Check this two images. Connect the device and run your app and look your device where you will get a popup saying installation is blocked, click on it and open then uncheck the toggle button.

[image: Block Installation] and [image: here disable it]

Comment: Is suggested solution helped you?

Comment: In my case, I don't see any toggle button: http://en.miui.com/forum.php?mod=redirect&goto=findpost&ptid=527200&pid=24005756

Comment: What was the initial issue? Is behaviour is same for all the app you are trying to install or only to specific app?

Comment: I'm trying to install it from Unity3D. It worked first time. Then that issue happens over and over. I did not try with other apps.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea.