# MIUI: By accident pressed remember and deny on ADB app install

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, adb, android-sdk-tools

By accident pressed remember and deny on ADB app install. Is there a way to reset it, as I want to compile and run that application. Changing of the app's package name doesn't do anything, so I'm afraid that I'm stuck with being unable to install that app onto my phone.

I'm currently using Pocophone(by Xiaomi) and I'm running MIUI Global 10.3.6 (Android 9 PKQ1.180729.001)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48838990/install-app-by-usb-install-canceled-by-user) question, although referring to a similar problem, doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: Is the app currently installed on the device?

Comment: @GaryStewart no, the app isn't installed on the device, furthermore, I think I've fixed it, as (like the link said) I've disabled the app installation block, although that popup didn't show until I manually ran the install command via terminal `adb install -r app.apk`

Answer (score 2):

If anybody is looking for a MIUI 14 solution:

Settings -> Apps -> Permissions -> Install via USB

Answer (score 1):

If you're lucky, you'll see a notification each time the app is blocked. Tapping this takes you to a screen where it can be re-enabled.

If notifications have been disabled for some MIUI apps, or the notification doesn't show, you'll have to navigate there manually:
Settings > Permissions (Almost at the bottom) > Install via USB.

Answer (score 0):

This is very hard to find manually. In Settings app search for "Permissions" in the search bar placed above, then select the Permission option that shows "Install via USB" on its list. Finally select "Install via USB" and uncheck the app you denied.