# Accidentally pressed don't allow install app and remember - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, debugging, xiaomi, miui

When I ran my app in Android studio, with my personal device, a notification was shown, and I accidentally pressed "remember action", and then pressed "don't allow". Now each time I try to run the app, I obtain an Android error, which says:

> 19:35 Session 'app': Installation did not succeed. The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED Retry

I've tried reconnecting the USB cable, however it didn't work.

Does someone know how to undo this?

Comment: I got answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48838990/install-app-by-usb-install-canceled-by-user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to developer configuration
2. Turn Off *Allow debug*
3. Turn On *Allow debug*
4. Connect again

It'll show you the alert again :D

Comment: where is allow debug?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Mi device then normally disable miui optimization under developers options, then try to reinstall the app and after the app get installed again turn on the miui optimization.

Comment: Thanks, that just saved me a significant amount of time! On my (relatively old) device this option was at the very bottom of the Developer options

Answer (score 2):

Go to `*Settings* => Permissions => Install via USB`.
For me it worked

Answer (score 1):

In MIUI 13 settings page search for "Install via USB" and select the security category option in results.
It contains rejected installs, simply deselect your app from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try again, and the notification informing you about the blocked installation will pop up. Click it and uncheck the application you want to install. You will be asked for permission to install again the next time you try to install the app. (Android 11)

Answer (score 0):

On miui 13 or 14, if you did so then clear the security app data and you are good to go.

Comment: Please do not yell or use unnecessarily noisy other formatting.

Comment: Also please explain what you mean by "you" and by "did so". All in all I think you need to do some [edit]ing and explaining to get this to be according to [answer]. Consider taking the [tour].