# Reenable the permission to install an App via Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, mobile

I accidentally denied permission and checked remember my choice on Android but I wanted to install it on my Android Device.

- I already tried disable Developer options and reenable them
- create a new Flutter Project just with the same code

For Information purposes I am using a Firebase Database and Firebase Authentication/SignIn.

I'm on MiUI on a Xiamomi Mi 9 SE.

[Install App By USB [Install canceled by user]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48838990/install-app-by-usb-install-canceled-by-user)

It is the same Problem as by @Atul Sharma.

I don't get the popup in an answer given.

Answer (score 0):

try :

1. when trying to install Goto apps -> permissions -> Install bia USB, give permission
2. Go to developer options, revoke usb debugging authorisation , toggle install via USB

one of the above should work